# Pygame Line of Sight from Fixed Position

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently working on a 2D game in which the player has to sneak up on a still person within a certain amount of time. There are various crates in the way (depending on which level it is), and I would like to make it so that the player can hide behind crates to sneak up on the still person.

---

[image]

I thought that I could use a cone-type vision for the person looking, but I'm not exactly sure how I would accomplish that. The player doesn't have to see the vision cone of the person looking either.

A similar effect to what I would like is in [this sample code](https://gist.github.com/marcusmoller/9538871) on github.

**NOTE:** The player cannot pass through the crates, and the people and crates are sprites.

Comment: Why would you not just calculate a line between the two people and check if it intersects with any of the boxes?

Comment: Looks like A* pathfinding to me. Use heuristics to determine in sight or not.

Comment: did my answer helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate the if the player is in line with the person, if it is you can check for every box if the 3 objects are ate the same position, if not you are in vision field `person_looking`. concidere player and person a `list` with coords.

```
def isInLine(player, person):
    deltaX = person[0] - player[0]
    deltaY = person[1] - player[1]

    if (person[0] == player[0]) or (person[1] == player[1]) or (abs(deltaX) == abs(deltaY)):
       return true
```

Like in a chess game, imagine you ahve to check if the king is in check by a queen. Its the same logic here.

Comment: Yes, very much so. It led me towards another idea to fix the problem which is very similar. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create an invisible projectile of a size of one pixel which you launch at desired angle towards player. You make it have some travel speed (say 2 pixels at a time) but instead of actually allowing the projectile to travel every frame you just loop for its travel untill it collides with something (either player or crate or end of level). So the whole emmision and collision process is done outside of while True main game loop in some function. You can emit it every second or something instead of every frame. And also you can emmit it in a cone shape either by scailing it's size every loop or emiting new one at different angle. If any of those collide with player mask or rect -> you have established a line of sight. This idea actually came to me right now out of the blue...
;)

On the second thought... maybe not 1 pixel size projectile but just collidepoint function. Just move your point from emmision origin to target at desired resolution.